# Swift - Where is the source file located that implements String

Tags: swift, string

Where can I find the file that implements the String API? I looked at the Swift.org repo put couldn't find it. For example, I want to see how (String.prefix(maxLength) -> Substring) is coded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`prefix(_ maxLength:)` is a generic method of the `Collection` protocol,
you'll find the implementation at [Collection.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Collection.swift#L1323):

```
  /// Returns a subsequence, up to the specified maximum length, containing
  /// the initial elements of the collection.
  ///
  /// If the maximum length exceeds the number of elements in the collection,
  /// the result contains all the elements in the collection.
  ///
  /// ...
  /// - Parameter maxLength: The maximum number of elements to return.
  ///   `maxLength` must be greater than or equal to zero.
  /// - Returns: A subsequence starting at the beginning of this collection
  ///   with at most `maxLength` elements.
  @_inlineable
  public func prefix(_ maxLength: Int) -> SubSequence {
    _precondition(
      maxLength >= 0,
      "Can't take a prefix of negative length from a collection")
    let end = index(startIndex,
      offsetBy: maxLength, limitedBy: endIndex) ?? endIndex
    return self[startIndex..<end]
  }
```

Now `String` is a `(RangeReplaceable)Collection` with the associated
`SubSequence` type defined as `Substring`, as one can see in
[StringRangeReplaceableCollection.swift.gyb](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/StringRangeReplaceableCollection.swift.gyb#L13):

```
extension String : StringProtocol, RangeReplaceableCollection {  
  /// A type that represents the number of steps between two `String.Index`
  /// values, where one value is reachable from the other.
  ///
  /// In Swift, *reachability* refers to the ability to produce one value from
  /// the other through zero or more applications of `index(after:)`.
  public typealias IndexDistance = Int

  public typealias SubSequence = Substring

  // ...
}
```

and therefore the generic method applied to `String` has the signature

```
func prefix(_ maxLength: Int) -> Substring
```

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the open source [Swift repo](https://github.com/apple/swift), you'll find it at `stdlib/public/core/String.swift`.

[Direct link](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/da6d960c9b18a344ed8eb1ba0e7879b1a1585a61/stdlib/public/core/String.swift)

I should add that, of course, the repo containing all Swift source code is massive and difficult to read without practice. Without a really good reason, I would default to saying that the implementation of a function (like your prefix example) is a detail the developer shouldn't be concerned about.

Comment: It doesn't seem that hard? I imagine for a compsci student analyzing the implemented algorithms can be valuable information.

Comment: Sure, and I'd call that a good reason. But if you're just doing iOS development, it is rare to need to know implementations of standard library functions.

Comment: I don't need to know the API implementation, I just want to look around to see how the code is written. What string APIs are they using within functions the most. Ways they string together APIs to do things. I figure I can learn a lot by studying there code.